# Minecraft Feed the Beast Revelation obtain list of category of items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

In Minecraft, modpack FTB Revelation I want to view all items of certain category, e.g. all edible items that can restore food points and their recipes, be able to look through them, filter them, sort them by number of food points they restore etc.. I was searching but couldn't find anything.

There are lists for individual mods, but not for the whole modpack and I don't want to go mod by mod. Is there a mod that can do it in game? Maybe filter in JEI?

Or is there a way to export certain recipes from the game along with their properies and recipes, so I would browse them externally? (I wouldn't mind if the export would require few lines of java or another language).